# How to secure Kibana dashboard using keycloak-gatekeeper?

Tags: kubernetes, kibana, keycloak, keycloak-gatekeeper

**Current flow:**

> incoming request (/sso-kibana) --> Envoy proxy --> /sso-kibana

**Expected flow:**

> incoming request (/sso-kibana) --> Envoy proxy --> keycloak-gatekeeper 
>   -->
>   keycloak
>
> --> If not logged in --> keycloak loging page --> /sso-kibana
>
> --> If Already logged in --> /sso-kibana

I deployed keycloak-gatekeeper as a k8s cluster which has the following configuration:

**keycloak-gatekeeper.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: keycloak-gatekeeper
  name: keycloak-gatekeeper
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak-gatekeeper
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak-gatekeeper
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: keycloak/keycloak-gatekeeper
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: keycloak-gatekeeper
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          args:
            - "--config=/keycloak-proxy-poc/keycloak-gatekeeper/gatekeeper.yaml"
            - "--enable-logging=true"
            - "--enable-json-logging=true"
            - "--verbose=true"
          volumeMounts:
             -
              mountPath: /keycloak-proxy-poc/keycloak-gatekeeper
              name: secrets
      volumes:
        - name: secrets
          secret:
           secretName: gatekeeper
```

**gatekeeper.yaml**

```
discovery-url: https://keycloak/auth/realms/MyRealm
enable-default-deny: true
listen: 0.0.0.0:3000
upstream-url: https://kibana.k8s.cluster:5601
client-id: kibana
client-secret: d62e46c3-2a65-4069-b2fc-0ae5884a4952
```

**Envoy.yaml**

```
- name: kibana
    hosts: [{ socket_address: { address: keycloak-gatekeeper, port_value: 3000}}]
```

**Problem:**

I am able to invoke keycloak login on /Kibana but after login user is not going to /Kibana url i.e. Kibana dashboard is not loading.

**Note:** Kibana is also running as k8s cluster.

**References:**
https://medium.com/@vcorreaniche/securing-serverless-services-in-kubernetes-with-keycloak-gatekeeper-6d07583e7382

https://medium.com/stakater/proxy-injector-enabling-sso-with-keycloak-on-kubernetes-a1012c3d9f8d

**Update 1:**

I'm able to invoke keycloak login on /sso-kibana but after entering credentials its giving 404. The flow is following:

**Step 1.** Clicked on http://something/sso-kibana
**Step 2.** Keycloak login page opens at https://keycloak/auth/realms/THXiRealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?...
**Step 3.** After entering credentials redirected to this URL https://something/sso-kibana/oauth/callback?state=890cd02c-f...
**Step 4.** 404

**Update 2:**

404 error was solved after I added a new route in Envoy.yaml

**Envoy.yaml**

```
  - match: { prefix: /sso-kibana/oauth/callback }
                route: { prefix_rewrite: "/", cluster: kibana.k8s.cluster }
```

Therefore, Expected flow (as shown below) is working fine now.

> incoming request (/sso-kibana) --> Envoy proxy --> keycloak-gatekeeper
>   --> keycloak
>
> --> If not logged in --> keycloak loging page --> /sso-kibana
>
> --> If Already logged in --> /sso-kibana

Comment: Hi, I am also trying to deploy the same in k8s with the help of traefik. I am facing the issue that http://something/kibana call is redirecting directly to http://something/ouath/authorize?state=<> without showing any login. I am not getting why it is redirecting to keycloak url. Keycloak gatekeeper logs show no erros, it does retrieve the openid settings successfully. Can you please help.

Answer (score 3):

In your config you explicitly enabled `enable-default-deny` which is explained in the documentation as:

> enables a default denial on all requests, you have to explicitly say what is permitted (recommended)

With that enabled, you will need to specify urls, methods etc. either via `resources` entries as shown in [1] or an commandline argument [2]. In case of Kibana, you can start with:

```
resources:
- uri: /app/*
```

[1] https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#example-usage-and-configuration

[2] https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#http-routing

Comment: Thanks for your reply I'm not sure what URLs, methods should I need to put in resources?